# How do I remove the space within a NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

This is my `NSMutableArray`. It contains a space in position 15.  When I store this in another `NSMutableArray`, it gives a null value.

How can I remove this space within the array in that particular position?

```
(
    12027,
    31100,
    27/02/2014,
     4:00AM,
    Infosys,
    Seonc item_shilpa,
    Client Visit,
    1,
      Tech,
    Shilpa Test,
    Scheduled,
    0,
    0,
    Anushka,
    3:15,
    Service Title: 2338Service Type: One Time

    ,
    Mysore
)
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the space between the words `Client Visit`?

Comment: i want remove the space in Srvice Title: 2338Service Type: One Time

Comment: are you creating this array by `componentsSeparatedByString:` method?

Comment: Yes.please help me remove the Space with this this element[Srvice Title: 2338Service Type: One Time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *str=[arrMessage objectAtIndex:index];
str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Srvice Title" withString:@"SrviceTitle"];
```

Comment: I want remove the space in Srvice Title: 2338Service Type: One Time

Answer (score 2):

Try this may it will help you

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()  \n\""];
s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *string=[yourArray objectAtIndex:15];

    NSCharacterSet *charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];

    NSString *newString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];

    [yourArray replaceObjectAtIndex:15 withObject:newString];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
customerDetails=[customerDetails1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

Here `customerDetails1` is converted array into string .

`customerDetails` is the another string to stored result string.
This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[yourArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *element, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    element = [element stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    [array addObject:element];
}];
```

Comment: I need to remove the whitespace with element not object

Comment: @Anupama here `yourArray` is mutable array created from `componentsSeparatedByString:`